# List all objects in Databricks (AWS) shared workspace

Tags: aws-databricks

We're doing a cleanup of our shared workspace and I need the code to list all objects in folders and sub-folders within that shared workspace.

I have both the instance name and the path, but just need the code.

I've tried other suggestions in SO, but received an error.

Instance name: Instance Name: scor-bigdata.cloud.databricks.com
Path: /Shared Workspace/CDO/

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code and list of notebooks

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
import base64
import requests
import json

databricks_instance ="https://databricks_instance.azuredatabricks.net"

url_list = f"{databricks_instance}/api/2.0/workspace/list"
url_export = f"{databricks_instance}/api/2.0/workspace/export"


payload = json.dumps({
  "path": "/Shared Workspace/CDO/"
})
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer user_token',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url_list, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
notebooks = []

# Getting the all notebooks list for given notebooks.

def list_notebooks(mylist):
  for element in mylist['objects']:
    if element['object_type'] == 'NOTEBOOK':
      notebooks.append(element)
    if element['object_type'] == 'DIRECTORY':
      payload_inner = json.dumps({
        "path": element['path']
      })
      response_inner = requests.request("GET", url_list, headers=headers, data=payload_inner).json()
      if len(response_inner) != 0:
        list_notebooks(response_inner)
  return notebooks

result = list_notebooks(response)
print(result[0])

#     print(current_note_book_id)
```

Comment: Thanks! When I attempt to run the code, I receive the following error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: SONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-148857020128483> in <cell line: 22>()
     20 }
     21 
---> 22 response = requests.request("GET", url_list, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
     23 notebooks = []
     24

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler to use new [Databricks Python SDK](https://pypi.org/project/databricks-sdk/) for that - it has built-in `list` function that can do a recursive listing ([doc](https://databricks-sdk-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/workspace/workspace.html#WorkspaceExt.list)). Install this lib with `%pip install -U databricks-sdk` and write something like this:

```py
from databricks.sdk import WorkspaceClient

w = WorkspaceClient()

names = []
for i in w.workspace.list('/', recursive=True):
    names.append(i.path)
```